# Custom item value resets after binding the ComboBox in C#

Tags: c#, combobox, telerik

I have a `RadDropDownList` `(Telerik component for ComboBox)`, in my application which I bind my database table items into.

```
public static void BindComboBox(RadDropDownList CB, string displaymember,
                                        string valuesmember, string sql)
{
            Connect = new SqlCeConnection(ConnectionString);
            SqlCeDataAdapter da = new SqlCeDataAdapter(sql, Connect);
            System.Data.DataSet ds = new System.Data.DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds);
            da.Dispose();
            CB.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
            ds.Dispose();
            CB.DisplayMember = displaymember;
            CB.ValueMember = valuesmember;
            CB.SelectedValue = null;
}
```

after binding my items in the ComboBox, I add an extra item to it:

```
RadListDataItem item = new RadListDataItem {Text = "All", Value = 0};
cmb.Items.Add(item);
cmb.SelectedItem = item;
```

But when I select this new item in my ComboBox and check the selected value, it's empty (not null).

What happens to the value I set to the item before adding it to the list?

**UPDATE**

I found out that even `cmb.SelectedItem = item;` doesn't work and `SelectedItem` remains `null` after running that line.

Comment: Does `new RadListDataItem {Text = "All", Value = 0}` have a property like `Selected = true`?

Comment: @PhongVo It does. but it doesn't work either.

Comment: How many columns do you have in `ds.Tables[0]`? and have you tried to removed `CB.SelectedValue = null;`?

Comment: @PhongVo i have two columns. and removing that line didn't make any diffrences

Comment: Can you paste the entire code please so we can see the sequence of the events.